# Solving a recurrence: T(n)=3T(n/2)+n

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science, recurrence

I need to Find the solution of the recurrence for n, a power of two if `T(n)=3T(n/2)+n` for n>1 and T(n)=1 otherwise.

using substitution of `n=2^m,S(m)=T(2^(m-1))` I can get down to:

`S(m)=2^m+3*2^(m-1)+3^2*2^(m-2)+⋯+3^(m-1) 2^1+3^m`

But I have no idea how to simply that.

Answer (score 8):

These types of recurrences are most easily solved by Master Theorem for analysis of algorithms which is explained as follows:

Let *a* be an integer greater than or equal to 1, *b* be a real number greater than 1, and *c* be a positive real number. Given a recurrence of the form -

T (n) = a * T(n/b) + n<sup>c</sup> where n > 1, then for *n* a power of *b*, if

1. Log<sub>b</sub>a < c, T (n) = Θ(n<sup>c</sup>);
2. Log<sub>b</sub>a = c, T (n) = Θ(n<sup>c</sup> * Log n);
3. Log<sub>b</sub>a > c, T (n) = Θ(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>).

---

**English translation of your recurrence**

The most critical thing to understand in Master Theorem is the constants *a, b, and c* mentioned in the recurrence. Let's take your own recurrence - T(n) = 3T(n/2) + n - for example.

This recurrence is actually saying that the algorithm represented by it is such that,

> (Time to solve a problem of size *n*) = (Time taken to solve *3* problems of size *n/2*) + *n*

The *n* at the end is the cost of merging the results of those *3* *n/2* sized problems.

---

Now, intuitively you can understand that:

- if the cost of "solving *3* problems of size *n/2*" has more weight than "*n*" then the first item will determine the overall complexity;
- if the cost "*n*" has more weight than "solving *3* problems of size *n/2*" then the second item will determine the overall complexity; and,
- if both parts are of same weight then solving the sub-problems and merging their results will have an overall compounded weight.

From the above three intuitive understanding, only the three cases of Master Theorem arise.

---

In your example, a = 3, b = 2 and c = 1. So it falls in case-3 as Log<sub>b</sub>a = Log<sub>2</sub>3 which is greater than 1 (the value of c).

The complexity therefore is straightforward - Θ(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>) = **Θ(n<sup>log<sub>2</sub>3</sup>)**.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this using Masters theorem, but also by opening the recursion tree in the following way:

- At the root of the recursion tree, you will have a work of n.
- In the second stage, the tree splits into three parts, and in each part, the work will be n / 2.
- Keep going until you reach the leaves. The entire work leaf will be: O (1) = O (n / 2 ^ k) when: n = 2 ^ k.
- Note that at each step m have 3 ^ m splits.
- Now we'll combine all the steps together, using the geometric progression and logarithms rules. In the end, you will get:
  T(n) = 3T(n/2)+n = 2n^(log3)-2n
  [the calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK1jf.png)

Comment: In the last line of calculation, you reduced `(3/2)^logN` to `N^log(3/2)`, IMO this looks wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here at page 60 http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs4205/files/CM2.pdf.

And maybe you should have asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm still lost on how to proceed. I don't get how you can simply the two different bases.

Answer (score 1):

The problems like this can be solved using [Masters theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)).

In your case `a = 3`, `b = 2` and `f(n) = n`.

So `c = log_b(a) = log_2(3)`, which is bigger than 1, and therefore you fall into the first case. So your complexity is:

O(n^{log_2(3)}) = O(n^{1.58})