# Complexity of a divide and conquer recursive algorithm

Tags: c, recursion, complexity-theory

I'm trying to obtain the complexity of a particular divide and conquer algorithm so transpose a given matrix.

From what I've been reading, I got that the recursion should start as follows:

```
C(1) = 1
C(n) = 4C(n/2) + O(n)
```

I know how to solve the recursion but I'm not sure if it's right. Everytime the function is called, the problem is divided by 2 (vars fIni and fEnd), and then another 4 functions are called. Also, at the end, swap is called with a complexity of O(n²) so I'm pretty sure I'm not taking that into account in the above recursion.

The code, as follows:

```
void transposeDyC(int **m,int f,int c, int fIni, int fEnd, int cIni, int cEnd){
    if(fIni < fEnd){
        int fMed = (fIni+fFin)/2;
        int cMed = (cIni+cFin)/2;

        transposeDyC(m,f,c, fIni, fMed, cIni, cMed);
        transposeDyC(m,f,c, fIni, fMed, cMed+1, cEnd);
        transposeDyC(m,f,c, fMed+1, fFin, cIni, cMed);
        transposeDyC(m,f,c, fMed+1, fFin, cMed+1, cEnd);

        swap(m,f,c, fMed+1, cIni, fIni, cMed+1, fEnd-fMed);
    }
}

void swap (int **m,int f, int c,int fIniA, int cIniA, int fIniB, int cIniB, int dimen){
    for (int i=0; i<=dimen-1; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<=dimen-1; j++) {
            int aux = m[fIniA+i][cIniA+j];
            m[fIniA+i][cIniA+j] = m[fIniB+i][cIniB+j];
            m[fIniB+i][cIniB+j] = aux;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm really stuck in this complexity with recursion and divide and conquer. I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the recursion wrong. It is 4C(n/2) + O(n<sup>2</sup>), because when joining the matrix back, for a size n, there are total n<sup>2</sup> elements.

---

Two ways:

1. [Master Theorem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34306747/1835769)

   Here we have a = 4, b = 2, c = 2, Log<sub>b</sub>a = 2

   Since, Log<sub>b</sub>a == c, this falls under the case 2, resulting in the complexity of O(n<sup>c</sup>Log n) = O(n<sup>2</sup> Log n).

---

2. Recurrence tree visualization

   If you'd try to unfold your recurrence, you can see that you are solving the problem of size n by breaking it down into 4 problems of size n/2 and then doing a work of size n<sup>2</sup> (at each level).

   Total work done at each level = 4 * Work (n/2) + n<sup>2</sup>

   Total number of levels will be equal to the number of times you'd have to divide the n sized problem until you come to a problem of size 1. That will be simply equal to Log<sub>2</sub>n.

   Therefore, total work = Log(n) (4*(n / 2) + n<sup>2</sup>), which is O(n<sup>2</sup> Log n).

Answer (score 0):

Each recursive step reduces the number of elements by a factor of 4, so the number of levels of recursion will be on the order O(log n).  At each level, the swap has order O(n^2), so the algorithm has complexity O((n^2)(log n)).

Comment: So, the recursion should be the following?

C(1) = 1
C(n) = 4C(n/2) + O(n²)