# How to solve T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + n*log(n) using recursive tree?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence, logarithm, master-theorem

I have a recurrence relation which is like the following:

**T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + n*log(n)**

I am using recursion tree method to solve this. And at the end, i came up with the following equation:

**n*( log(n/2^0) + log(n/2^1) + log(n/2^2) + .......+ log(n/2^(log n)))**

on solving this equation, i got time complexity as **n(log n)^2**
but by using **master's theorem** i got time complexity as **n(log(log n))**
please help me in finding my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take the equation you have here:

> n(log(n/2<sup>0</sup>) + log(n/2<sup>1</sup>) + log(n/2<sup>2</sup>) + ... + log(n/2<sup>log n</sup>))

Now, let's use properties of logarithms to rewrite log(n / 2<sup>k</sup>) as log n - log 2<sup>k</sup>. This gives us

> n((log n - log 2<sup>0</sup>) + (log n - log 2<sup>1</sup>) + (log n - log 2<sup>2</sup>) + ... + log n - (log 2<sup>log n</sup>))

Another property of logarithms tells us that log 2<sup>k</sup> = k log 2. The log base isn't specified here, so for simplicity I'm going to assume they're base-2 logs. That means that log 2<sup>k</sup> = k. That means that we have this expression:

> n((log n - 0) + (log n - 1) + (log n - 2) + ... + (log n - log n))
>
> = n(log n + (log n - 1) + (log n - 2) + ... + 2 + 1 + 0).

You might recognize this inner sum as Gauss's sum: 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + k = k(k+1) / 2. That means that this sum simplifies down to

> n (log n)(1 + log n) / 2
>
> = **Θ(n log<sup>2</sup> n)**.

Which matches what the Master Theorem says. That's great news!

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong. You will git `n log^2(n) = n * log(n) * log(n)` as well (the seocnd case). See more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) (case 2a).

We know that `a = b = 2` and it means `c_crit = 1`. Hence as `f(n) = n log(n) = Theta(n log(n))`, and it means `k = 1 > -1`.

Answer (score -1):

[Master Theorem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34306747/1835769) is not applicable for this recurrence because the cost of merging, which is n * Log(n) in your recurrence, has to be a power of n.

However, if you take n * Log(n) to be upper bound by n<sup>2</sup>, then you can apply Master Theorem. It will yield a complexity of n<sup>2</sup> Log(n) in that case.

Further, as we have taken a looser bound on the cost of merging, therefore this complexity is looser as well. Your complexity of n * Log<sup>2</sup>(n) could be more correct/tighter bound.

Comment: There is a version of the Master Theorem that does allow for log terms in the additive part of the expression, and you can apply that here. However, depending on which version of the Master Theorem the OP is learning about, that tool might not be available here.